# Addition or subtraction of lag terms in the autocorrelation expectation formula?

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation, stationarity, lags

I have some confusion about autocorrelation. In my notes I have defined,

$$r[k] = E[y[n]y^*[n-k]]$$

Is this the standard way of writing autocorrelation?

What are conditions such that $r[k] = r[-k]$?

Which would imply that $$r[k] = r[-k]= E[y[n]y^*[n+k]]$$

Also, why is the conjugate on the second term?

Can we also write the formula as this:

$r[k] = E[y^*[n]y[n-k]] = E[y^*[n-k]y[n]]$ ?

So what conditions would properties like these hold (addition, subtraction of lag term, conjugation, order of variables), if there are any?

Hopefully this can uncover something that's been seeming a little mysterious to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of auto-correlation slightly changes among disciplines. Some define it as normalised version of auto-covariance. Yours is also correct. Autocorrelation function has the conjugate symmetry, i.e. $r[k]=r^*[-k]$. To remove the conjugacy, you'll need real signals, i.e. $y[n]=y^*[n]$.

If the signal is complex, you can also write $r[k]=E[y[n+k]y^*[n]]$, but not $E[y^*[n+k]y[n]]=r[-k]$.